# What kind of wall texture is on this wall?

Tags: drywall, texture

My initial thoughts were orange peel, but I'm not entirely sure as it appears different? Tried to take photos with different lighting.

[image] [image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: If you need to do repairs to it, ask as a separate question. Wood-chip is the easiest of all finishes to patch up, but there's a trick to it which deserves its own QA imo.

Comment: Where in the world are you located?

Answer (score 2):

This is a type of wallpaper known as *woodchip*
Colloquially it's known as *anaglypta** in the UK and *ingrain* in the US.

The inventors of the method of encapsulating small chips of wood between two sheets of paper themselves call it woodchip, so this should be considered the 'correct' name. [See Erfurt & Sohn; More than just wallpaper!](https://www.erfurt.com/en/company/company-history/)

*Anaglypta is a trade name, adopted in the same way as hoover or spackle as a generic term.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess *("I'm not really into drywall texturing, nor textured drywall, personally")* is that it's a larger/sparser "splatter" texture where "orange peel" is a finer/denser "splatter" texture (and "splatter" is also the precursor to "knockdown" - but this has not been knocked down...

Plus what looks like quite a number of subsequent coats of paint over the years.

Either that, or it's actually "popcorn" sprayed (sparsely) on the wall, which is unusual as that's normally just done to ceilings.

Answer (score 0):

I've been enlightened about a wall covering called "[ingrain wallpaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingrain_wallpaper)", which is composed of layers of paper with embedded wood chips. This seems like a near exact match for what you've shown.

[image]
Image: [Fagato](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Fagato)/Wikipedia